# Twilio javascript SDK .sendDigits example needed -

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-javascript

I have tried a dozen ways to make a button on a webpage that's got a connected Twilio client voice call perform .sendDigits.  This is the most recent try.

```
const dtmf_1 = document.getElementById('DTMF1');
dtmf_1.onclick = function(){call.sendDigits('1')};
```

This returns

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: call is not defined at dtmf_1.onclick (quickstart.js:46:79)
```

Frankly, I have no idea if fixing the reference is even going to work.
Does anyone have an example of working code that will play a DTMF tone on a live call with the Twilio JavaScript SDK?

Comment: The code example you have provided is correct in terms of sending a digit to an active phone call. As you have mentioned the issue lies in that your variable containing the call is undefined when you are attempting to send the digits. This is likely a scoping issue of where the call is defined and where you are trying to send the digits. Please can you provide code examples for where you are defining the call and more on where you are attempting to send the digits

Comment: I just fixed the scoping issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a timely comment by Tristan Blackwell (see above), I was able to fix this issue which was indeed a scoping problem.

The fix was to put the line

`dtmf_1.onclick = function(){call.sendDigits('1')};`

right under the line where the call is connected.

`const call = await device.connect({ params });`

Like so

```
      const call = await device.connect({ params });
      dtmf_1.onclick = function(){call.sendDigits('1')};
```